# Manipulating text files in java

Tags: java

I want to display all the customers stored in text files, but one customer is stored in many text files and he is displayed more then once. How to eliminate duplicates of these customers? I have tried  even with HashSet but didn't work. Here is my code.

```
public class ReadFile {

private int countCustomer = 0;  
private File path;
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public ReadFile(File file_path) {

    path = file_path;

}

public String[] openFile() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        textData[i] = br.readLine();

    }

    br.close(); 
    return textData;
}

public void arrayCustomer(){

    try{
        String[] array = openFile();    
        for (int j=0; j< array.length;j++)   
        {
            String str = array[j];  
            String[] temp;
          String delimiter = " ";   

          temp = str.split(delimiter);

          String category = temp[0];  
          double balance = Double.parseDouble(temp[1]);   
          int moveNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);    
          int accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp[3]); 

          if (!isIn(new Customer(category, balance, moveNumber, accountNumber)))
          {
        customers.add(new Customer(category, balance, moveNumber, accountNumber)); 
        countCustomer++;
          }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public boolean isIn(Customer customer){

    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++){
        if (customers.get(i).getAccountNumber() == customer.getAccountNumber())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void listCustomers() {
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        System.out.print("Category: " + customer.getCategory());
        System.out.print(" Balance: " + customer.getBalance());
        System.out.print(" Moves: " + customer.getMoveNumber());
        System.out.println(" Account number: " + customer.getAccountNumber());
    }
}


public int readLines() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int numberOfLines = 0;
    String aLine;

    while((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
        br.close();
        return numberOfLines;
}



// The class with the main method

public class FileList {

public static Scanner scan;
public static ReadFile f;
public static final File folder = new File("C:/My_dir");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("textfiles");
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {   
        File fileEntry = listOfFiles[i];

        if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) 
        {
            try{
                f = new ReadFile(fileEntry);
                f.openFile();
                f.arrayCustomer();
                f.listCustomers();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        else
            {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "The directory is empty!");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Set` should do the trick if your `Customer` is correctly defined. You need to make sure your `Customer` has both an `equals()` and `hashCode()` object which operate on the same set of fields and can correctly identify whether two customers are "the same" or not as defined by your business criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you be more explicit writing some code?

Comment: Of course. My standard rate for writing code for people is £60/hour. Or, you could go and Google around some of the stuff I've mentioned, maybe learn something for your homework instead of being spoon-fed an answer, and then come back with specific questions once you've tried it again for yourself. Would you like my Paypal address? Or would you like to Google? :-)

Comment: +1 for the snarky response as much as for the correct answer.